# Accessing to total number in each second level(Postgres Hierarchical Query Practice)

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical

I was practicing on Postgres and stuck on a point that I couldn't find a way to achieve. I have a simple database which are the attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE public.department
(
"deptId" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
"parentId" integer,
"numEmpl" integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "department_parentId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("parentId")
    REFERENCES public.department ("deptId") MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

and then I have some data in the table. Short example is

```
insert into department values (1, 'Headquarter', 1, 10);
insert into department values (2, 'Sales', 1, 15);
insert into department values (3, 'Logistics', 1, 25);
                      ...
```

I was trying to get the total number of people who are employeed in each second level department.

I am able to get the total number of employeed people in each department but according to my search in the internet this is possible with "Hierarchical Queries". Currently, I am using

```
parentId=1
```

while querying.

Any solutions for this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "second level department"?

Comment: According to table that I have, a person can be an employee of a parent department. So that, a department can have descendant departments.

Comment: I don't understand how you can have "second level" departments if there are no "first level" departments where `"parnentId"` is null.

Comment: There is no null "parentId". So if there is no parent department, then the department is pointing itself. @JonathanJacobson

Comment: That's a poor design choice imho, and @GMB should change the solution according to what you just wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select deptid as rootid, deptid from department where parentid = 1 and deptid <> 1
    union all
    select c.rootid, d.deptid
    from cte c
    inner join department d on d.parentid = c.deptid and d.deptid <> 1
)
select rootid, count(*) cnt from cte group by rootid
```

Comment: May I ask that what is "rootid" in this given example? Or is it "deptid rootid"? I am trying to learn, sorry if it is a simple question.

Comment: "rootid" is an alias for `deptid`. This could also be written as `SELECT deptid AS rootid`.

Comment: @JSpratt I got used you use AS all the time. It is good to know. However, with this example which is provided by "GMB" never stops executing. It keeps saying "Waiting for the query to complete"

Comment: @Metalian: you have rows where the parent and child have the same name, hence the infinite loop. I changed the query a little to avoid that.